# Wrap vertical wooden column with drywall

Tags: drywall

I want to wrap this vertical wooden beam with drywall so that it blends in with drywall near chilling area as you can see in picture.

[image]
I have done some drywall repairs in wall but haven't done something like this. I know that I just have to screw drywall pieces on all 4 sides and use joint compound followed by some sanding. But not sure how can I achieve straight 4 corner edges. any tips or links to online articles will be appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Look for a [corner bead](https://www.homedepot.com/p/10-ft-Vinyl-Corner-Bead-CBRVYLUPC10/306632722) at your local home improvement place:

[image]

Comment: Welcome, Your answer **needs to explain** what the OP should do and how they should do it, not just " you need this part " and link.   Please read the tutorial on how to answer in order understand how to post proper answers. https://diy.stackexchange.com/help/how-to-answer *If they do not know what corner bead is they probably do not how to install it correctly*.

Comment: Thank you. This looks like what I need.